# Python 3.5 CentOS 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos, pip

I have massacred my Centos 7 release trying to get python 3.5 and pip working. After installing from source and trying lots of things I won't get into I found the following guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-centos-7

I was very happy and everything seemed to go perfectly. The guide even talks about installing pip3.5 :D

The problem i now face is that pip3.5 is installing packages in the following location:

```
/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages
```

but python 3.5 is looking in the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

I think this might be a mix up from having first build python 3.5 from source. Can someone please tell me how to get python to look in the lib64 location for site packages?

Comment: After endless trouble i decided to reinstall a clean version of centOS and install python again with the above guide. This fixed the problem. For anyone stuck with weird python 3.5 / pip mismatches in centOS my recommendation is to reinstall and try again rather than wasting time trying to fix it...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it would be better to install Python 3.5 as described in https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-python35/

```
# 1. Install a package with repository for your system:
# On CentOS, install package centos-release-scl available in CentOS repository:
$ sudo yum install centos-release-scl

# On RHEL, enable RHSCL repository for you system:
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms

# 2. Install the collection:
$ sudo yum install rh-python35

# 3. Start using software collections:
$ scl enable rh-python35 bash
```

I have no problem after it

Comment: i''ve since moved to python 3.6

Comment: In this, Python 3.6 is set as the default Python version only in that shell session. If you exit the session or open a new session from another terminal Python 2.7 will be the default Python version. How to make python 3.6 the default?